# Generate a query that changes a single element on multiple rows PHP MySQL

Tags: php, sql, post, associative-array

I'm working on a homework assignment that involves PHP. Basically, I have a page that contains a web form that renders items pulled from a database. There's checkboxes on each row and 2 radio buttons. The user selects "accept" or "deny" and when submit is clicked, the items that are checked are supposed to change to that approval status. All of the items in the form are submitted into post. I thought that post is an array so I could just use a while loop with a counter so that the loop traverses through the array and when it gets to the last index (which should contain approve or deny). A query is generated that changes all of the previous indexes to approve or deny. I'm sorry if this isn't making much sense.
[Here's a picture for more clarification](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/201/webform.png/)

Here's the code I used to generate the webform:

```
<?php
       #create a query string
       $query = "SELECT * FROM Request WHERE superemail = '$user'";
       #echo $query;

       #run the query
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('error querying');

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
              #print out each row of the queryi
              #line up the query results with temporary strings
              $change = $row['KEY'];
              $name = $row['first']. " " . $row['last'];
              #echo $name;
              $email = $row['email'];
              #echo $email;
              $type = $row['type'];
              #echo $type;
              $duration = $row['duration'];
              $status = $row['status'];

              #create a table row with the query results

              echo "<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=$change /></td>
              <td>$name</td>
              <td>$email</td><td>$type</td>
              <td>$duration</td><td>$status</td></tr>";

      } #end while
  ?>
  <label for=update>Change status to:</label><br />
  <input type=radio name=update value=A />Approved<br />
  <input type=radio name=update value=D />Denied<br />
  <input type = submit value = "Change Status" />
```

Comment: You need to show us some code so that we know you've put forth an effort. It also helps us debug a situation when someone doesn't fully understand the problem yet. Give us the PHP code and HTML.

Comment: what's the question? starting your post with "I'm working on a homework assignment" with no code supplied isn't going to get you much help.

Comment: Change status to close. This is now being handled with JavaScript and asychronized JQuery AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Each `input` tag (your checkboxes and your radio button) in your html should have a name attribute, such as: `<input type='radio' name='accept' value='1' />`.  When the form is submitted and processed by PHP, your script will be able to access that info at `$_POST['accept']` (or `$_GET['accept']` depending on the form's method).

So you should be able to specify a name for the radio button, then check to see if there is a value in the POST array at that index.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume a few things. First, that it is a design goal of yours to only process items in your approval queue that you choose to select, leaving the others alone. Second, that you want to change their status to what is chosen in a radio button. Third, that you want both a code snippet and an explanation as to how the task got accomplished.

So, here goes.

You have a series of checkboxes; I assume they have the same name. If you wish for the values to be passed to PHP as an array, you absolutely need to name the inputs `whatever[]` with emphatic emphasis on the `[]`! This is what creates an array from the checkbox to appear in the $_POST/$_GET. Only those items selected will appear in the array. The value ought to be something useful (A value in the corresponding database table, say) which you can select for and query on...after sanitizing the input, of course.

So, your HTML input tag should look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="process[]" value="<?php echo $employeeName ?>" >
```

You should have this coming back at you...

```
$_POST['process'][array(0=>name1, 1=>name2/*...etc*/)]
```

...which you can loop through with a foreach at your leisure.

Comment: The name on the check boxes corresponds to the ID field or the corresponding database row.